# compressing strings with a static dictionary

Tags: java, performance, compression, latency, throughput

This will be a bit abstract question since i don't even know if there are any developments like this.

Given we have an application which tries to deliver text data from point A to B.
A and B are quite far away so size of the data has significant effect on all important metrics we want to optimize for (speed, latency and throughput). First thing that comes to mind is compression, but compression is not that effective when we have to compress many many small messages but its very effective when the size of the compressed data is significant.

I have no experience with compression algorithms but my understanding is that bigger the input the better can be the compression rate since there is a bigger likelihood of repeating chunks and things that can be optimized.

One other way we could go is batching, by waiting for some N period of time and collecting all tiny messages and creating one compressed big one we could have good compression rate but we would sacrifice latency, the message that arrives first will take unnecessary delay of N.

Solution that I'm looking for is something like this, when a compression algorithm traverses the data set it is probably having some dictionary of things that it knows can be optimized. This dictionary is thrown away every time we finish with the compression and it is always sent with the message to B.

`rawMsg -> [dictionary|compressedPayload] -> send to B`

however if we could have this dictionary to be maintained in memory, and be sent only when there is a change in it that would mean that we can efficiently compress even small messages and avoid sending the dictionary to the other end every time...

`rawMsg -> compress(existingDictrionaryOfSomeVersion, rawMsg) -> [dictionaryVersion|compressedPayload] -> send to B`

now obviously the assumption here is that B will also keep the instance of dictionary and keep updating it when the newer version arrives.

Note that exactly this is happening already with protocols like `protobuf` or `fix` (in financial applications).
With any message you have schema (dictionary) and it is available on both ends and then you just send raw binary data, efficient and fast but your schema is fixed and unchanged.

I'm looking for something that can be used for free form text.

**Is there any technology that allows to do this (without having some fixed schema)?**

Comment: Since you're asking to recommend a library I think your question might be better on the Software Recommendations site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Personally I don't know of any technology that does exactly what you are asking for.  It might be best to design your software flexibly ("Strategy Pattern") so that the actual compression is well isolated and can be switched out easily.

Comment: compressed by gzip if require lower transfer size, however if require transfer large data, better to use another thread and transfer by steam

Comment: @markspace it is designed that way, its no effort for me to plug anything, but the results for gzip are not worth it, especially for small messages... and since its free form text i cant just come up with some protobuf msg...

Comment: have you tried snappy? It's not as good compressing, but it is super fast. Maybe you could give it a try...

Comment: @slee forget about threading and common scene optimizations i think i did them well, at the moment i have a dedicated thread pinned on a specific core, and it is able to process messages (serialize and compress them) faster than they arrive, my bottleneck is the network, and i cant just spawn multiple connections, i need the ordering to be the same... in short i need to make payloads significantly smaller without batching...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner havent used it but if it has streaming mode, and is smart enough to dynamically improve compression using previously observed messages then its a great option... does it do that? or for every message it starts from blank page?

Comment: I have messages that sometimes are exact duplicates, or are wrapped in other messages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send the many small messages in a single compressed stream. Then they will be able to take advantage of the previous history of small messages. With zlib you can flush out each message, which will avoid having to wait for a whole block to be built up before transmitting. This will degrade compression, but not nearly as much as trying to compress each string individually (which will likely just end up expanding them). In the case of zlib, your dictionary is always the last 32K of messages that you have sent.

Comment: so it always transmits the dictionary even if nothing changed?

Comment: There is no separate dictionary to send. The "dictionary" is simply the last 32K of uncompressed data.